# Change chmod for a specified group

Tags: linux

How to change chmod of a group ID 601 using chmod command?

Comment: ...what?  This question no sense.  `chmod` changes permissions; it has very little to do with groups, except inasmuch as it sets permissions for the file's group.

Comment: try to make the question more informative otherwise it will be closed soon i think.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very unclear, but if you are trying to set access rights for a group that is not the group owning a file, file access control lists (FACL) are your friend. `man getfacl`.

Comment: The only other thing I would add is chirp may be what you are looking for as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `chown` instead:

```
chown :601 myfile
```

This change group ownership to group 601. Then, you can change group permissions with `chmod`

```
chmod g+rw myfile
```

Add read/write permissions to the owner group.